# convert sql column from varchar to bit with data retained

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, bit, varchar

I have a legacy table in Sql Server which has a `varchar(5)` column that can be `true` or `false`.

I would like to run a script that basically changes the column type to bit and then goes over the data and changes the `true` values to `1` and everything else to `0` in that column.

The table is very small if that matters. Can anyone give me a hand here?

Answer (score 4):

I would do the conversion in three steps, as follows:

1. Add a bit column
2. Copy data using a single `UPDATE`
3. Drop the `varchar(5)` column

Here is an example script that implements this approach:

```
create table test(flag varchar(5));
insert into test(flag) values ('true'), ('false'), (null);
-- #1: Add a bit column
alter table test add fbit bit;
-- #2: Copy data using a single `UPDATE`
UPDATE test
SET fbit = CASE
        WHEN flag = 'true' THEN 1 
        WHEN flag = 'false' THEN 0
        ELSE NULL 
    END
-- #3: Drop the varchar(5) column
ALTER TABLE test DROP COLUMN flag
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8354b/1) Note that SQLFiddle prints `true` and `false` for bit columns, but the actual data is a bit, not a `'true'` / `'false'` strings.

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with bits can be a pain.  The following would work for a numeric type, but I'm not sure if it works for bits:

```
update t
    col = (case when col = 'true' then 1 else 0 end);

alter table t
    alter column col bit;
```

Also, you can convert the strings "true" and "false" directly to bits, so if these are the only values, then the following should work:

```
alter table t
    alter column col bit;
```

If this doesn't work, then other options are:

- Use a tinyint instead.
- Add a bit column and set it.  Then drop the original column and rename the bit column.
- Save the data into a temporary table, drop the original table, reconstruct it with the proper data structure and re-load the data.